# is there a script that can delete empty from last column and last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to delete empty columns and empty row from last column and last row, but don't want to delete empty columns on the left of last column that contains data and empty rows above the last column that contains data. OpenAi generate this code but it didn't work. Can somebody please assist me in this? Thanks a lot!

```
function removeEmptyColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastDataRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastDataRow, lastColumn);
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

  var lastDataColumn = lastColumn;
  for (var col = lastColumn; col > 0; col--) {
    var empty = true;
    for (var row = 0; row < lastDataRow; row++) {
      if (dataValues[row][col-1] !== "") {
        empty = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (empty) {
      lastDataColumn--;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (lastDataColumn < lastColumn) {
    sheet.deleteColumns(lastDataColumn+1, lastColumn-lastDataColumn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed your expected result is as follows.

- You want to delete rows and columns except for the data range in Google Spreadsheet.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  const maxRowsData = dataRange.getNumRows();
  const maxColsData = dataRange.getNumColumns();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  if (maxRows - maxRowsData > 0) {
    sheet.deleteRows(maxRowsData + 1, maxRows - maxRowsData);
  }
  if (maxCols - maxColsData > 0) {
    sheet.deleteColumns(maxColsData + 1, maxCols - maxColsData);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the outer rows and columns of the data range are deleted.

#### References:

- [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)
- [deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumnscolumnposition,-howmany)